# 4-digit numbers with two of the same digit

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 4-digit numbers (including leading zeros) have exactly one digit appearing twice?

Here's what I thought:

There are $\binom{4}{2,1,1} = 6$ digit "layouts", with $c$ as the repeated digit: $abcc, bacc, accb, bcca, ccab, ccba$

Then there are $10 \times 9 \times 8$ ways to assign digits $0$ thru $9$ to $a, b, c$.

I also thought that this would over-count strings where $a$ and $b$ are swapped, for example $abcc$ and $bacc$. To check I wrote some code and apparently it isn't over-counted. I think I am missing something simple - the way I assigned digits to $a, b, c$ means I can't over-count layout $abcc$ with $a=1, b=2$, and layout $bacc$ with $a=2, b=1$? This should be simple but I am confusing myself.

Comment: You are indeed overcounting twice.  But you also seem to be missing $cabc$,  $cacb$, $acbc$ (and those with $b$ and $a$ swapped).

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think you're right, $\binom{4}{2,1,1} \ne \binom{4}{2}$. I think I got confused about the question of the two digits appearing consecutively.

Comment: @RobertIsrael can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Comment posted as an answer, as requested]

You are indeed overcounting twice. But you also seem to be missing cabc, cacb, acbc (and those with b and a swapped).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way to solve the problem, which you’ll recognize as essentially the same as yours.

Start by selecting the two places that will hold the same digit (in any of $4\choose 2$ ways). For each of those pairs of places, select which digit to put there (in any of $10\choose 1$ ways). For each of those placements of a digit in two places, select the digit to put in the leftmost still-empty place (in any of $9 \choose 1$ ways). For each of those fillings of three spaces with exactly two digits, select which digit to put in the last still-empty place (in any of $8 \choose 1$ ways).

So the 4-digit numbers fitting your specifications number
$${4 \choose 2}{10\choose 1}{9\choose 1}{8\choose 1} = 4320$$
ways.

Comment: This didn't answer my confusion though. Robert Israel already pointed out my mistake.

Comment: I’d suggest that this solution does address what your confusion was if you look at it and compare it to what your logic was looking like. In any case, I’m glad his comment scratched your itch.